# How do I load UIView subview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios7

I'm trying to use a nice looking control, but cannot figure a) how to load data and b) how to convert this control to a storyboard.

The control is [here](https://github.com/bennyguitar/CollapseClick)

My code to load the titles of subviews works fine.

```
-(NSString *)titleForCollapseClickAtIndex:(int)index {
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return @"Item Information";
            break;
        case 1:
```

I cannot figure how to load this next method:

```
-(UIView *)viewForCollapseClickContentViewAtIndex:(int)index {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return  itemView;
            break;
```

(UIView *) ItemView (after initializing) is:

```
- (void)loadElements
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    [self.item setText: @"try this"];
    self.category.text = @"category";
    self.date1.text = @"todays date";
    self.date2.text = @"another date";
    self.serial.text = @"serial no";

} return self;
```

The view is drawn in IB, and has connections to these items. The UIView is also drawn in the main xib. It gets to show as in the demo, with titles from the ItemView class.

As I mentioned, the titles are inherited from the view controller. The text (e.g. @
try this", do not..

If I try to log a text field in the "viewForCollapseClickContentViewAtIndex" method, I get an run time exception:

```
2014-01-17 07:54:44.856 CollapseClickDemo[29037:70b] -[UIView item]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c84590
2014-01-17 07:54:44.858 CollapseClickDemo[29037:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView item]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c84590'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x024531e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015808e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x024f0243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0244350b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x024430ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   CollapseClickDemo                   0x000034b8 -[ViewController viewForCollapseClickContentViewAtIndex:] + 152
    6   CollapseClickDemo                   0x0000ca89 -[CollapseClick reloadCollapseClick] + 1561
```

Comment: What are "the runs"? Post any console output/error output that's relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I have edited the question (the last sentence), and added a log output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `[self.item setText: @"try this"];`

This is the cause of your exception. `self` (which seems to be your control) doesn't have an `item` property. `self.item` is equivalent to `[self item]`, and since there's no method named `item`, you get an unrecognized selector exception.

Once you get it working, you can add it to a storyboard by adding a scroll view to the storyboard (because your widget is a subclass of UIScrollView) and then changing its class to `CollapseClick`. AFAIK, there's not currently a way to add user-defined classes to the list of classes supported by the storyboard editor.

Comment: Caleb, I'm confused. I thought that the ItemView class would return a UIView called itemView, and itemView just has some textFields. Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Oh, but thanks for the tip on using UIScrollviews for UIViews in storyboards. +1 for that.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte It's hard to understand from your Q what class that `-loadView` method belongs to, but whatever class it is, it doesn't seem to have an `item` property. Look at the error message you're getting: *reason: '-[UIView item]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c84590'*. You're somehow sending the message `-item` to an instance of plain old UIView, and since UIView doesn't have an `-item` method, you get the exception.

Comment: OK. once more.. I have an instance of UIView. It holds the textfields. When I populate the fields, and then log the view, it contains the textfields as expected. However, when I load the view in a view controller, the text fields are not there. So I get the exception. I can't figure out what I'm missing..